# Can methods return exceptions?

Tags: java, methods

Well im really new to java and im really trying hard to understand what can be done in java and what can't. I'm making a console application based on the well known game Hangman. Basiclay what i'am trying to do is stop the user from typing 'e's more than twice, to do that i made 2 methods:

The first one adds 1 to the int variable **mManyTimes** whenever the user types e.

```
  public boolean adder() {
   boolean tooMuch = letter == 'e';
   if(tooMuch) {
     mManyTimes ++;
   }
   return tooMuch;
  }
```

the second method is the one that sends an exception
to the user when the user types e more then twice.

```
public void cheatStopper() {
  if(mManyTimes == 3) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cant type more Es");
  }
 }
```

Basicly i created two files, one that holds the code of the game(Which those two methods are in) and other one.

the file that holds the logic of the game is **Game.java** and here is the code that is inside it:

```
public class Game {
  private String mAnswer;
  private String mHits;
  private String mMisses; 
  private int mManyTimes;
  public char letter;

  public Game(String answer) {
    mAnswer = answer;
    mHits = "";
    mMisses = "";
  }

  public boolean applyGuess(char letter) {
   //checks for char letter inside the mAnswer variable.
   //If it is there the indexOf() method should return the index of the letter.
   //If it is not  there it will return -1.
   //We are basicly saing if indexOf() method returns 0 or more then that then the isHit 
   //if it is not then the isHit boolean will return false.
   boolean isHit = mAnswer.indexOf(letter) >= 0;

   if (isHit) {
    mHits = mHits + letter;
    } else {
      mMisses = mMisses + letter;
   }
   adder();
   return isHit;


  }

  public boolean adder() {
   boolean tooMuch = letter == 'e';
   if(tooMuch) {
     mManyTimes ++;
   }
   return tooMuch;
  }

 public void cheatStopper() {
  if(mManyTimes == 3) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cant type more Es");
  }
 }
```

The other file that holds the **main()** method and prints the code to the console is **Hangman.java**:

```
    public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Enter amazing code here:
        Game game = new Game("treehouse");
        game.applyGuess('e');
        game.applyGuess('e');

        System.out.println(game.cheatStopper());
    }

}
```

So here is the question that frustrated me and i never found and answer for:
How do i get my code to work and stop the user from typing more then two e.
Well well i know my code has many errors and bad structure but dont forget that im new to java, and thanks for advance :).

Comment: Your title and your post are asking two different questions. As for your title: Yes methods can return Exceptions. Exceptions are objects, after all.

Comment: `return` and `throw` are two different concepts and just so happen to be keywords in Java

Comment: You could have got this googling "how to handle exceptions java", btw.

Comment: `cheatStopper` will only throw the exception if there's 3 `e`s typed. Try chanhging the 3 to 2 and the exception will be thrown

Comment: You can return an Exception from a method but this is very rarely done. Usually you throw an Exception in an method.

Comment: Well I had two questions in my mind that's way my content and title are different but whay can i print cheatStopper to the console then.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `catch` block. Look up how to catch exceptions.